# Проблемы Wordpress: переход по другому адресу

Tags: wordpress

Вообщем проблема у меня такая. Пару тройку месяцев назад сайт поймал вирус, весь код сайта был просмотрен и отчищен. Последствия были таковы. При входе на сайт перекидывала на другую страницу и антивирус еще срабатывал, все вычестили стало хорошо. Сайт стоит на вордпрессе, но проблема еще осталась, когда человек оставляет коментарий к той  или иной записи на почту приходит извещение, типа вам написали коментарий, там есть ссылка - перейти по ссылке чтобы прочесть комментарий, переходим - но переходит по другому адресу http://yandexbot.cz.cc/in.cgi?40

И такая же проблема с поисковиками, когда нашел запрос любой относительного моего сайта в поисковике, переходим по ссылке и опять тот же адрес. вот можете посмотреть в поисковике как это происходит http://www.google.ru/#sclient=psy-ab&hl=ru&newwindow=1&source=hp&q=site:forsign.kz&pbx=1&oq=site:forsign.kz&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=2510l11992l0l12199l17l16l1l0l0l0l324l3655l0.3.9.3l16l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=6282ad232143c65c&biw=1600&bih=778

Кто то может сталкивался с данной проблемой, кто что знает подскажите, что можно сделать, все перепробывал уже.

Answer (score 2):

Значит не все вычистили, без осмотра файлов так просто не сказать где собака зарыта. Так что советую сделать бекап базы и поставить его полностью на новый вордпресс скаченый с официального сайта, так даже будет лучше, малоли может хакеры оставили бекдор где в движке. Если проблема не исчезнет то смотрите файлы своего шаблона, возможно найдете там какой либо подозрительный код, смотрите uploads картинки которые могут оказаться совсем не картинками и .htaccess на это может намекать ;) Если все выше описанное не помогло то остаеться только база данных, где нибудь в таблице настроек например ибо прописывать зловреда в каждый пост просто не круто и много гемороя.